# S3 sync exclude piggyback of .gitgnore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is there anyway to specify for the `aws s3 sync` command to exclude file patterns as outlined in an `.gitignore` file?

I have a code build pipeline which I want to trigger but have it run against my local files for testing changes I don't want to check-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to convert the `.gitignore` information into the `--exclude` format expected by the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

See: [Using High-Level s3 Commands with the AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html)

Comment: If you have a script I'll give you a tick ( ; haha Otherwise I will write my own one once I muster up the motivation.